# What is the difference between handleChange vs OnChange in which is used in React?

Tags: html, reactjs

Please can someone explain to me the clear difference between handleChange vs onChange in used like below in React? `<Component handleChange = {this.handleChange}>`.

If I change the `handleChange =` above to `OnChange =` what difference will it make?

Comment: `handleChange` is a custom prop, `OnChange` is a native React Synthetic event: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Answer (score 1):

handleChange is just the prop name used in your Component.

Going to the component specs you will actually see that it acceepts handleChange as prop an then whatever is passed here as this prop is used in components returning markup in onChange attribute (which is an actual js event)

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using onChange. I've ran into similar issues before. For example:

```
    //set the initial state fields to all be empty
    const authState = { fullName: '', email: '', password: '', confirmedPassword: ''};

    //create a new set of data for the form and set the initial state as the empty fields above
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(authState);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        // console.log(event.target.value);
    };

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} class="authform">
            { isSignup && (
            <>
              <Input required name="fullName" label="Full Name" placeholder="Full Name" onChange={handleChange}/>
            </>
            )}
            <Input required name="email" label="Email Address" onChange={handleChange} type="email" placeholder="johnsmith@email.com" />
            <Input required name="password" label="Password" placeholder="password" onChange={handleChange} type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'} 
                endAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <IconButton onClick={handleShowPassword}>
                        {showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                }
            />
            { isSignup && <Input required name="confirmPassword" label="Repeat Password" onChange={handleChange} type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'} placeholder="Confirm Password"/> }
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
            { isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In' }
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={switchMode}>
                { isSignup ? 'Already have an account? Sign in' : "Don't have an account? Sign Up" }
            </Button>
        </form>
```